# Cypress insert wrong data from JSON

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am experiencing quite an odd issue regarding Cypress testing .
Everything is running smoothly in my test suites , but sometimes I am facing a weird behavior .
When a I fetch a input field and insert something in it like :

```
cy.get('#input-column-start-date-0').type(testdata.customer.date.insert.first)
```

JSON test data :

```
 "testdata" : { 
    "customer" : {
      "date" : {
       "insert" : {
        "first" : "18-02-2020"
        ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But the oddest thing is that sometimes Cypress is able to fill in the correct string and sometimes it skips some of the letters
The result is like :  `"18-2-020"`

So I ask myself am I doing something wrong ? Did I skipped something from Cypress documentation ? I just wonder , because this issue is really annoying .
I would be very happy if someone give me a hand and resolve my issue here . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try increasing the delay option (delay after each keypress), which defaults to 10ms

```js
cy.get('#input-column-start-date-0')
  .type(testdata.customer.date.insert.first, { delay: 100 })
```

Comment: It seems that it is doing the job right . I gave it a try with a couple of test cases and did not catch any miss typing . What is the cause of that ? I mean the scenario is faster then the UI loads ? Do you have some more information about this issue ?

Comment: I found the type command to be a bit unpredictable sometimes, but not sure why. It does more than just a "paste" operation, take a look at [Events that fire](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Events). On top of that, the app may have event handlers that execute per key (onChange event) and if it lacks proper debounce you can get skipped keys.